# Can I become head of all factions in Morrowind?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

On Elder Scrolls Oblivion and Skyrim you can join all factions and become the leader. I'm also playing Morrowind and I'd like to know if I can do the same, because I've read that some guild missions conflict with other guild missions.

Comment: Again, a more descriptive title would be very beneficial.

Comment: Just so you know, you can't use "guild" and "faction" interchangeably. Skyrim factions are Stormcloaks and Imperials, while Skyrim guilds are thieves, Dark Brotherhood, etc. For the life of me, I can't seem to remember any Oblivion factions (that you can side on)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes certain factions conflict with each other. I tried to keep the following list relatively spoiler-free so I apologize for vagueness.

**Great Houses**

The Great Houses of Morrowind are mutually exclusive and as such, you can only join one of the three choices (Hlaalu, Telvanni, or Redoran) without the use of a bug.

**Everything Else**

The Fighters Guild quest "The Code Book" is in direct conflict with the Thieves Guild and will make it so you can not join the Thieves Guild. There is a way to get around this as explained on the wiki page linked below.

Any Fighters Guild quest offered by Sjoring Hard-Heart make the Thieves Guild hate you at a minimum or kicked out of it at a maximum.

A Tribunal Temple quest, "Slay Raxle Berne", will block off being able to join the Berne vampire clan.

The last one I can find deals with the Mages Guild. One of the final quests they give you will make it so you can no longer be a part of House Telvanni.

---

There is an entire wiki page dedicated to quest timing that talks about conflicting quests. You can find it [here](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Quest_Timing).

Comment: You're somewhat overstating few things. Code Book *is* better done before being in Thieves - you can simply convince the girl. Later it's pretty hard to do without causing trouble (unnoticed stealing it  is needed). Also one doesn't even need to get this crazy task from Archmage, and it's the most problematic way to replace him.